# Little help here putting logic on icons

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have this list

```
final List<String> entries =  <String>['Life', 'Car', 'Car'];
```

then i try to generate 3 widgets each one with an icon depending on the values that have the array i tried in this way

```
 children:<Widget>[
              Icon(
                 entries=='Life'? Icons.favorite_border:Icons.directions_car,
                 color: Colors.white,
                 textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                 size:50,
                ),
```

but all widgets get the favorite_border icon instead of mixing between directions_car and favorite_border.

Answer (score 0):

entries is a list, you can't compare it with a String. Use map in entries list to generate it to a list of Icon.

List icons = [Icons.favorite_border, Icons.directions_car,...]

```
entries.map<Icon>((String entry) {
  return Icon(
    icons[entries.indexOf(entry)],
    color: Colors.white,
    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    size:50,
    )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to verify each item in your array. Like this below:

```dart
children: <Widget>[
  ...entries.map(
    (icon) => Icon(
      icon == 'Life' ? Icons.favorite_border : Icons.directions_car,
    ),
  )
],
```